# Calculator for calculating price per feet amounts

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

So I have a customers site I am remaking into an mvc3 app and they have an existing JavaScript pricing calculator.  Is this safe and efficient?  I am no JavaScript guy, but it looks pretty solid to me.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {

        //Carpet
        var ppf = .25; //price per square foot, edit this to suit
        //tile
        var ppfTile = .50; //price per square foot, edit this to suit
        var ppfVCTWood = .60; //price per square foot, edit this to suit
        var ppfTravertine = .60; //price per square foot, edit this to suit

        df = document.carpet;
        df[0].focus();
        df[2].onclick = function () {
            df[0].focus();
        };
        df[0].onkeyup = function () {
            if (isNaN(df[0].value)) {
                alert('numbers only please');
                df.reset();
                df[0].focus();
                return;
            }
            df[1].value = '$' + util.formatCurrency(df[0].value * ppf);
            df[2].value = '$' + util.formatCurrency(df[0].value * ppfTile);
            df[3].value = '$' + util.formatCurrency(df[0].value * ppfVCTWood);
            df[4].value = '$' + util.formatCurrency(df[0].value * ppfTravertine);
        };
    };
    var util = {
        formatCurrency: function (num) {
            num = isNaN(num) || num === '' || num === null ? 0.00 : num;
            return parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);
        }
    };
</script>
```

And here is the form.

```
<form name="carpet" action="#">
<div id="container">
    <h2 style="font-size: 12pt;">
        Cost Estimate</h2>
    <label>
        <input class="inp" type="text" />
        : Enter Square Footage</label>
    <br />
    <label>
        <input class="inp" type="text" value="$0" readonly="readonly" />
        : Estimated Cost For Carpet</label>
    <br />
    <label>
    <input class="inp" type="text" value="$0" readonly="readonly" />
    : Estimated Cost For Tile </label>
    <br />
    <label>
    <input class="inp" type="text" value="$0" readonly="readonly" />
    : Estimated Cost For VCT and Wood </label>
    <br />
    <label>
    <input class="inp" type="text" value="$0" readonly="readonly" />
    : Estimated Cost For Travertine Tile </label>
    <br />
    <input type="reset" />
</div>
</form>
```

I am worried this is old and outdated. Could I do this more effectively with C# in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few thoughts. Some are probably overkill, but I'm just brainstorming.

Overall, it seems fairly solid if a little outdated. JohnP mentioned the bit about hard-coded prices, and I agree, but it's a question of maintainability rather than robustness.

I'd be concerned about directly assigning a function to `window.onload`. While it works, it also precludes you from adding other on-load functions later (you'd have to do some extra work at least), and/or you risk overwriting other onload handlers, or them overwriting yours. Libraries like jQuery will handle multiple event handlers for you, but if you want to avoid loading a library, there are still [alternatives to attaching event handlers directly](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html).

On the markup side, I'd give all the inputs proper IDs or at least name attributes, and refer to them that way in the JavaScript. The `someform[nth_input]` way of getting elements works, but it's pretty oldschool, impossible to understand without the markup, and easily breaks if you add more inputs to the form. Meanwhile something like `document.getElementById("square_footage")` is pretty self-explanatory. More verbose, yes, but much clearer.

I'd also consider using something besides `input` elements for the calculated prices. Technically, any element would work, and be eaiser to style than an `input` element. Since the fields are all readonly, they really aren't *inputs* anymore anyway. In your case, I'd probably use a table element (since it's monetary stuff) with ID'd `td` elements, and set their content with `innerHTML`.

The `df[2].onclick = ...` bit makes little sense to me. There are 4 fields with calculated values, so why does one in particular get a click-handler? Furthermore, the click handler makes it difficult for a user to (for instance) select the calculated price in that input and copy it. I just fail to see the point - seems like some old, left-over code.

Lastly, the `util` object ends up in the global scope, which is generally bad practice. Like `window.onload` you risk overwriting something or being overwritten by something. It doesn't need to be there, though. If `formatCurrency` is defined inside the `onload` function, it'll be available there without polluting the global scope.

Answer (score 3):

About the only thing that I don't like in it is that you have to edit the code each time a price changes. I'd prefer that to come from a dynamic source, especially if you are going to use it in more than one spot.

Comment: Hmm good point, right now it's only in one spot on one page.  I could make some sort of datasource that would be easy to add/delete from.  Other than that it seem pretty solid and not too old/outdated?

Comment: Yeah, it seems all right, but if you are recoding to MVC3, how long would it take to recode the calculator? Stylistically, unless it's time prohibitive, having it all in a contiguous language might be preferable, unless they have JS sprinkled all through the code.